# changing nemeserver and website is not collable

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I got the error after changing the Nameserver.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

i add the server with ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.
the dot on the and. Is that correct? i have only to wait?

i tryed with and without the dot iam not sure which one is right. iam waiting now bit more as 24 hours. i also add the dns record for the ip adress to google cloud dns.

[image: you see the squarespace settings]

Comment: What DNS records for your domain have you created on googledomains.com?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.

Comment: I created a a record for the ip adress the SOA and NS is created by google

Comment: where did you create your A record? Did you use A record in cloud DNS?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add the “dot” at the end of the name server. Make sure that in your Cloud DNS, A record is set and pointed correctly to your external IP address follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/set-up-dns-records-domain-name) as a guidance on how you can set your A record.

Once you use the name server of cloud DNS and place it in your domain registrar DNS which is shown in your screenshot, the A record of your domain should be in Cloud DNS. Any record, should be on Cloud DNS.

To check, you can use this [link](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) if your domain is propagating, another way to check is to [dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/) the domain. Place in the domain, click A from the link, it indicates the A record then check if external IP address is correct.

Comment: zou are mz hero the tool is amaying my populating is only 50%